# Cookie is not persisting across multiple pages PHP

Tags: cookies, php

I'm going nuts figuring this out. I'm new to PHP

I'm simply trying to put a querystring variable inside a cookie and have it available across all pages on the site. What's happening now is that it only sets the cookie when there is a querystring and the cookie is gone once I go to another page.

All my php pages have this code at the top:

```
<?php

$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;

if (isset($_GET['v'])) {
$thev = $_GET['v'];

if (!isset($_COOKIE["ckv"])) {
setcookie("ckv", $_GET['v'], $expire);
}
} else if (isset($_COOKIE["ckv"])) {
$thev = $_COOKIE["ckv"];
} else {
$thev = 'nothing';
}
?>
```

1. page1 WORKS! (shows cookie)
2. page1 no querystring WORKS! (shows cookie)
3. page2 BROKEN. (Cookie gone!)

** These were clicked in order. So page 3 should be displaying the cookie

Thank you

Comment: Is page2 in a different directory or subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the above answer, look into using SESSIONS in stead of $_COOKIE. They are much more flexible and significantly safer than cookies

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: But... they do a diffferent job. If you build an application for a stateless server farm, then PHP sessions are practically useless (you need to backup with cookies and database). If you have want to share data from server to Javascript (on page load) then sessions can't do this so easily (cookies can). You may want a session that's shorter than a cookie (but don't have permission to change the session length on your server). Sessions are also lost if the server restarts (so you need to back up by cookie + database). Different things, sessions have their place, cookies have theirs.

Answer (score 0):

There can be three answers I can see for this.

The most likely is that page 1 and page 2 are in different directories. By default a cookie is placed in the current directory (as specified in the browser - ignoring any includes/apache redirects etc), and will apply to that directory and below ONLY. You if you have

```
/dir1/page1 
/dir2/page2
```

then a cookie in page 1 will not, be default, be available in page 2.

You can get around this by specifying the path ([see documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)). Here you declare the directory to which the cookie wil apply - most commonly you would set this to '/' (root) which means apply to any page in the application.

---

Now some gotchas:

As you've already got a cookie in '/dir1/', if you modify your code to include a path of '/' and run, then you'll actually have two cookies - one at '/' and one at '/dir1/'. Your page 1 will still get the '/dir1/' cookie unless you delete it first. Also check you don't have a blank cookie in '/dir2/' as well (i.e. that you get "nothing" in your code, not blank space - which means you have a cookie but with a blank value). Having cookies in sub-directories can cause a lot of frustration.

Other possible causes are to do with caching (make sure you're not caching values) and also different domains (you can't share cookies across domains, and if you want to share across sub-domains then you need to specify the root domain - see documentation).